# XSL page encoding

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using xslt 1.0 to transform some xml returned via a Server.Execute on an .aspx page. In Google Chrome if I use the following XSLT encoding:

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
```

I get a space left at the top of my transformed XML.
If I use this encoding:

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes" />
```

The space has gone, but things like £ display as �. Never truly understood which encoding I should be using. Can anybody point me in the right direction please? Thanks.

Comment: Thumbs up to UTF-8 .. "iso-8859-1" is local to Latin :) For unwanted space, why don't you try `strip-space` ??

Comment: Thanks for the response. It really odd, the white space doesn't seem to be being generated by any elements. It's just there at the top of the transformed XML code.

Comment: Could you paste that XML? And the whole XSL?

Comment: Why omit the XML declaration - that lets Chrome know what encoding the XML document it is reading it in.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately this caused another problem in some browsers because it was trying to display the XML declaration within the page code, again causing unwanted white space.

Comment: Your attributes are inconsistent. The xml-declaration only applies to XML output. As you have specified html output, it is ignored. You say you get a space left at teh top of your "xml" but your output is (or is specified as being) html not xml. Are you sure it is a space and not a BOM character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you use the utf-8 encoding the output file starts with a prefix indicating the encoding - a sequence of two characters `0xEF` and `0xBB`, and this prefix is the extra space you are seeing.

You can check if this is the case saving the file and checking if the prefix is there - and see if the problem goes away manually removing the prefix.

When using iso-8859-1 (or other non-Unicode encoding) there is no prefix, and hence no problem, but using non-Unicode encodings usually is a bad idea because it creates problems handling non-ASCII characters.

To have UTF-8 output without the prefix use an `XmlWriter` as follows:

```
  XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
  settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
  using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(response.OutputStream, settings)) {
     // . . . apply the XSLT sending its output to 'writer' . . .
  }
```

where `response` is the `HttpResponse` of the HTTP request being served.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for your response.